# is there any way to Simulate DCM in ISIM?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, test-bench

I have a DCM with different clock outputs which is working fine in real FPGA implementation, but could not see any input while simulate this DCM in Xilinx ISIM. Can we simulate DCM in ISIM testbench? Is there any trick?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, make sure that simulation is running and wait enough time.

Comment: The simulation is running for enough time, but it does not show any clock output from DCM. While if I use clock directly from testbench, it works fine. Have you any experiment with ISIM using DCM, please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Yes, It worked fine now in ISIM. Sorry I was issuing very small reset signal. Thanks